# Getting Sinatra to work with JRuby and Warbler

Tags: sinatra, jruby, warbler

I'm using the following config/warble.rb in my hello-world-style application:

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  config.dirs = %w(app config tmp gems views)
  config.includes = FileList["hello.rb"]
  config.gems = ["sinatra"]
  config.gem_dependencies = true
end
```

Now when I run jruby -S warble this is the error message:

```
warble aborted!
uninitialized constant Warbler::Jar::Pathname
org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2526:in `const_missing'
```

Can anyone help me out with it? The application runs without problems when executed directly so it looks like I have all the required gems installed.

Environment:

- JRuby 1.6.1 (same with 1.5.6)
- Sinatra 1.2.6
- Warbler 1.3.0
- Windows XP
- Ubuntu 10.04.1

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround for this that works with both ruby and jruby.

Instead of specifying the gems inside config/warble.rb I've installed the Bundler gem and created Gemfile in the root folder of my application with the following content:

```
source :rubygems
gem "sinatra"
```

With that removed from the config/warble.rb file the actual content of this file looks like this:

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  config.includes = FileList["hello.rb"]
end
```

To summarize:

- gems go into the Gemfile
- application files go into the config/warble.rb file

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out there's an obvious bug in warbler preventing this functionality to work under jruby 1.6.1 and ruby 1.8.7 (don't know about other versions because I didn't test it).

Take a look here for a quick fix:

https://github.com/padcom/warbler/commit/b4b24e17dee5bb98525203c82519a8901874ef81